# What is the technical name for the "Tap to translate" button from GoogleTranslate app?

Tags: mobile, material-design, drag-n-drop, tap, floating-action-button

When copying some text on Android, Google Translate displays a floating button on the side of the screen (top / right) that can be tapped to translate or just dragged up and down to not be obstructive.

[image]

What is the technical name of it?

It looks like a *coin*, but I cannot find any specific name or pattern for the implementation (in web development with JS/CSS) of these buttons.

Answer (score 2):

#### Material refers to this as a [Floating Action Button](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) (FAB).

The transition to a menu shown in your example is considered one of the potential uses

[Types of transitions](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions)

> Upon press on Android, the FAB can transform into a menu containing related actions. A scrim indicates that functionality outside of the action menu is temporarily disabled. The menu remains on-screen until an action, or the scrim, is tapped.

**Here's a snapshot example from the docs when a FAB turns into a menu:**
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend expanding on the FAB being a "floating action button." I read OP's question as more asking about the actual button rather than the menu ("...a floating button on the side of the screen...It looks like a *coin*..."), but good information nonetheless. I haven't seen these kinds of FAB transitions before, so this was interesting.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reference, is still good info. But *maxathousand* nailed what I was actually asking (a side -floating & draggable- button).

Comment: ah yes...It is a Floating Action Button, as for the name.